# error results when add code to register user notification settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am trying to register for user notification for my app using Xcode 6 beta 6 and coding in swift. Below is my code, it causes two apple mach-o errors that are also below.

Any idea how to fix? Am I doing something wrong in the code?

**UPDATE:**
If I leave just one notification type it works fine, so I think the problem is the " | " separator, what is the correct way to do it? Everywhere I look has it like that.

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))

    return true
}
```

Errors:

```
    Ld /Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/--.app/-- normal armv7
    cd /Users/christopherbonilla/--/--/--
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Intermediates/--.build/Debug-iphoneos/--.build/Objects-normal/armv7/--.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lswiftCore -L/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Intermediates/--.build/Debug-iphoneos/--.build/Objects-normal/armv7/--.swiftmodule -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework Foundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreBluetooth -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Intermediates/--.build/Debug-iphoneos/--.build/Objects-normal/armv7/--_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/christopherbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/---esgnlherkoqgtbczodawinrqohqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/--.app/--

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__TFSsoi1oUSs17_RawOptionSetType_USs21BitwiseOperationsTypeSs9Equatable__FTQ_Q__Q_", referenced from:
      __TFC11--11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTGSQCSo13UIApplication_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSQCSo12NSDictionary__Sb in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to the: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete the content. This has solved all mach-o errors in beta 6 by me.

Comment: You have saved so much time I hope you find the secret for immortality